# Set a Custom Label for App Builder Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, app-builder

Is it possible to set a custom label for the name of a Lightning Component in the App Builder? In the example below, my component is named "DashboardPage" - can I change the label to something else, or do I have to rename the entire component?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You need to create a design file for the component:

```
<design:component label="Label For Component">
</design:component>
```

See the *Add a Design Resource to Your Component Bundle* section in the dev guide at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder.htm